# Symfony2 Array to string conversion, set empty value

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig, output

I`am rendering a twig template in symfony2 and its possible to get a variable with value of array type but i am trying to preview the variable and this error pops:

> Array to string conversion ...

So my qustion is not how to print out the array, but is it possible in twig to disable this error, so when an array comes and it cannot be outputed, to set an empty value.

In config.yml, under twig i have set

> strict_variables: false

But this dose not include printing arrays.

EDIT:

In controller I pass this array to twig, for example:

```
'data' => array(
            'description' => array(
                  'desc1', 
                  'desc2'
            )
         );
```

In twig I am trying to print {{ data['description'] }} and I got the following error:

> Array to string conversion ...

This is the normal error that must pop, but I need if I try to print this a no error to pop but instead I need to print nothing(empty value), same way like trying to print an non existing variable with twig set with

```
strict_variables: false
```

ANSWER:

Make a custom function:

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
       'to_string' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'toString')
    );
}

public function toString($data) {
    if(is_array($data)) {
        return '';
    }
    return $data;
}
```

And in twig template:

```
{{ to_string(data['description']) }}
```

Comment: To print an array you can use `print_r`, `var_export` or `var_dump`, but you should access the data inside with the array indexes. Post your array to show you how to access data

Comment: im confused... are you trying to print the contents of the array, or display nothing if it is an array?

Comment: Fix the error, do not walk around it. It is not acceptable to echo a array and try to supress it. Please add you code (minimal example)

Comment: Why don't you iterate over the array an print out every single value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You have two desc: `desc1` and `desc2`, what do you want to print? If both you have to use this notation (for instance)</strike>

```
{{ data['description'][desc1] }} - {{ data['description'][desc2] }}
```

More in general:

```
{% for desc in data['description'] %}
    {{ desc }}
{% endfor %}
```

### EDIT

Ok, now I got it (from your comment):

```
{% if data['description'] is iterable %}
    //echo here an empty string
{% else %}
    {{ data['description'] }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I want to print {{ data['description'] }} and I don't want the error for Array to string conversion ...

Just an empty value to be printed.

Comment: `data['description']` isn't a scalar value so, "I want to print it out" is a nonsense statement

Comment: Yes that is the problem, I need something in twig, where if I am trying to echo an array the response to be an empty value(string)

Comment: Is theyere another way, becouse I could have a lot of this and if i have to do it every time it is not so cool.

Something like:

strict_arrays: false

Comment: @user3686982: you have to use an iteration statement like `for` or `while`. BTW this answered your question

Comment: Ok I have found something, if I do {{data['description']|number_format}} it makes my array to integer it outputs 0. So I could make a fitler for checking the variable and if is array - output is empty string.